# SwfitData: Unsupported relationship key path ReferenceWritableKeyPath<>

Tags: swift, swift-data

I am using swiftData for persistence. And I have a Task class with a one to many relationship to SubTask class. When I tried to mock a Task object, it shows the error: `Unsupported relationship key path ReferenceWritableKeyPath<SubTask, Task>` 
They will fail in preview, but they can be successfully built. 
I have my code below: 
Task:

```swift
enum TaskSchemaV4: VersionedSchema {
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 2, 0)

    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [Task.self]
    }

    @Model
    final class Task {
        @Attribute(.unique, originalName: "id") var id: UUID
        @Attribute(originalName: "created_at") var createdAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "updated_at") var updatedAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "deleted_at") var deletedAt: Date?
        @Attribute(originalName: "name") var name: String
        @Attribute(originalName: "note") var note: String
        @Attribute(originalName: "status") var status: String
        
        @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \SubTask.task) var subtasks: [SubTask]? = []
        
        @Transient var isFocused: Bool = false

        convenience init(name: String, subTask: [SubTask]? = nil) {
            self.init(id: UUID(), createdAt: Date.now, updatedAt: Date.now, deletedAt: nil, name: name, note: "", status: DoingTaskStatus)
        }

        init(id: UUID, createdAt: Date, updatedAt: Date, deletedAt: Date?, name: String, note: String, status: String) {
            self.id = id
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.updatedAt = updatedAt
            self.deletedAt = deletedAt
            self.name = name
            self.note = note
            self.status = status
        }
    }
}
```

SubTask:

```swift
enum SubTaskSchemaV1: VersionedSchema {
    static var versionIdentifier = Schema.Version(1, 1, 0)
    static var models: [any PersistentModel.Type] {
        [SubTask.self]
    }

    @Model
    final class SubTask {
        @Attribute(.unique, originalName: "id") var id: UUID
        @Attribute(originalName: "created_at") var createdAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "updated_at") var updatedAt: Date
        @Attribute(originalName: "name") var name: String
        
        @Attribute(originalName: "task") var task: Task

        init(id: UUID, createdAt: Date, updatedAt: Date, name: String, task: Task) {
            self.id = id
            self.createdAt = createdAt
            self.updatedAt = updatedAt
            self.name = name
            self.task = task
        }

        convenience init(name: String, task: Task) {
            self.init(id: UUID(), createdAt: Date.now, updatedAt: Date.now, name: name, task: task)
        }
    }
}
```

When I mock a Task, it shows the error: Unsupported relationship key path ReferenceWritableKeyPath<SubTask, Task>

```swift
extension Task {
    static var example: Task {
        let task = Task(name: "a task", subTask: [])
        let subtask1 = SubTask(name: "a subtask", task: task)
        task.subtasks?.append(subtask1) // error shows when add this line.
        return task
    }
}
```

I tried the answer in [SwiftData/PersistentModel.swift:540: Fatal error: Unsupported relationship key path ReferenceWritableKeyPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77382754/swiftdata-persistentmodel-swift540-fatal-error-unsupported-relationship-key-p) , the error is gone, but the subtask isn't added in task.

```swift
extension Task {
    static var example: Task {
        let task = Task(name: "Task", subTask: [])
        let subtask1 = SubTask(name: "subTask", task: task)
        return task
    }
}
```

My Preview code:

```swift
struct TaskCardView: View {
    @Bindable var task: Task
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var ctx
    
    var body: some View {
        ... // some code to show task and subTask.
    }
}


#Preview {
    let container = PersistenceContainer.preview
    let task = Task(name: "Task", subTask: [])
    let subtask1 = SubTask(name: "SubTask", task: task)
    container.mainContext.insert(task)
    return TaskCardView(task: task).modelContainer(container)
}
```

Comment: You should add your preview code but my guess the issue with your last code is that the relationship doesn't work because neither of the objects has been inserted into a model context.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Sorry for didn't add my preview code, I just added. The way I write in preview still don't work.

Comment: Try doing the insert before you set the relationship, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77500310/9223839